# Using sed to search-and-replace contiguous matches in pipe-delimited files

Tags: csv, sed

I have a pipe-delimited datafile that I want to load into Mysql via LOAD DATA INFILE.

Something like:

```
a|||d|e
x|y|z|0|1
...
```

I want replace an empty field with `\N` so that the data is recognized as a NULL value.

doing

> sed 's/||/|\\N|/g'

almost works, but not quite - in that first data line, the second pipe is eaten up by sed so that the second contiguous empty field isn't parsed!!!

*My hacky work-around is to pipe the result of the first sed to do another identical search and replace a second time to get rid of those contiguous empty fields.*

**My question is, what is a more elegant way to get around this problem in sed (preferably in one pass)?**

TIA.

**Additional Note**

If you plan to process your data file with sed, please also watch out for end of line cases like this:

> h|i|j|k|

You will need to pipe to

> sed 's/|$/|\\N/g'

to handle those end-of-line cases.

Also, if you are going from DOS to UNIX systems, you may want to erase '\r' from your data file using sed search-and-replace.

I recommend that you account for all warnings from Mysql when using LOAD DATA INFILE - they will help you catch the evil cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the repeat (`t`) command:

```
echo 'a|||d|e' | sed ':repeat; s/||/|\N|/g; t repeat'
```

Comment: looks good - ty... ...will accept as solution if nothing better comes along!